# dbcontext.entity.select not available in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2012, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-6

it's been a while since I work with EntityDataModel. I used to do things like:

```
var listaProductos = dbContext.Productos.Select(p => new
```

I just started a new web project with asp.net and added the entity data model but If i try to do the same as the example above I can't use ".Select". Do I need to install any Nuget package or something?

I work with Visual Studio 2013.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add namespase to your file:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: @mason this works with types, but doesn't work with extension methods

Comment: Thanks! It works. Is there any way to be added automatically by Visual Studio?

Comment: @alma this namespace, usually added if you creating empty cs file.

Answer (score 0):

check your namespace and dbContext class.

Like

```
using ContosoUniversity.Models;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;

namespace ContosoUniversity.DAL
{
    public class SchoolContext : DbContext
    {

        public SchoolContext() : base("SchoolContext")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }
    }
}
```